# Reuse a function inside another controller which is not attached with view

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to reuse a function inside another controller belongs to another page. It has not been attached to the view of current page. I followed these steps:

1. Include the controller by using script tag
2. use $on and $emit in order to call the function

Unfortunately, nothing happened. That controller is still initialized normally however it does not receive calling from $emit.

I greatly appreciate if someone can help me to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? Angularjs has the concept services which is specifically meant for this purpose - code reusability. All you need to do is create a service, and inject it in your controllers to use it. See below.

```
app.service('hexafy', function() {
   this.myFunc = function (x) {
     return x.toString(16);
   }
});
```

And then in controller,

```
app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, hexafy) {
   $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(255);
});

app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, hexafy) {
    $scope.hex = hexafy.myFunc(1023);
});
```

Remember that services in angular are singleton.

Comment: I already known about service concept however cause came from my stupid mistake. I tried to call services/controllers belong to another window in Electron environment. That window was separate from other one so calling was unsuccessful. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR:* That is most likely because you should be using the `$broadcast` method instead of `$emit`!

In the [Angular's documentation of `$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), we can find that:

> ### `$emit(name, args);`
>
> Dispatches an event name **upwards** through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered `$rootScope.Scope` listeners.

Whereas:

> ### `$broadcast(name, args);`
>
> Dispatches an event name **downwards** to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered `$rootScope.Scope` listeners.

Check out the comprehensive code snippet below. You can play around with the emitters and see what the receivers are notified about!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ReceiverCtrl', ['$scope', function ListenerCtrl($scope) {
  this.count = 0;
  $scope.$on('my-event', function(e, data) {
    this.received = '\'my-event\' has been ' + data + '!';
    this.count++;
  }.bind(this));
}]);

myApp.controller('EmitterCtrl', ['$scope', function EmitterCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.clickEmit = function() {
    $scope.$emit('my-event', 'emitted');
  };

  $scope.clickBroadcast = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('my-event', 'broadcasted');
  };
}]);
```

```css
div[ng-controller] {
  padding: 16px;
}

div.receiver {
  background-color: steelblue;
}

div.emitter {
  background-color: hotpink;
}

.console {
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #eee;
}

.console::before {
  content: '> ';
}

.highlight {
  color: white;
}

button {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ReceiverCtrl as outer" class="receiver">
    <div class="console">{{outer.received}}</div>
    received total: <span class="highlight">{{outer.count}}</span>
    <div ng-controller="EmitterCtrl" class="emitter">
      <button ng-click="clickEmit()">$emit()</button>
      <button ng-click="clickBroadcast()">$broadcast()</button>
      <div ng-controller="ReceiverCtrl as inner" class="receiver">
        <div class="console">{{inner.received}}</div>
        received total: <span class="highlight">{{inner.count}}</span>
        <div ng-controller="EmitterCtrl" class="emitter">
          <button ng-click="clickEmit()">$emit()</button>
          <button ng-click="clickBroadcast()">$broadcast()</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however I suppose that cause does not come from method used. In my opinion, cause could be the controller did not initialized properly and it had not been attached to the my module. I did not assign it to any ng-controller directive on view layer so AngularJS skipped in bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

I realized there is no way to reuse a controller as my expection. My solution was attached it into an empty invisible tag. However I welcome if someone can show a better solution for this situation.